# Can protein folding destroy cryptography?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization

They say that [protein folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_folding) is an [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problem, meaning that if we could figure out how any protein folds, we could solve any NP problem in polynomial time. However, doesn't this basically destroy the field of cryptography?

Suppose I want to factor a large [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime). Couldn't I convert it into a protein folding problem, then create that protein in real life and see how the protein folds, and then factor the number? Or couldn't I use the machine learning software [AlphaFold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaFold) to solve the protein problem for me and then factor the large semiprime?

Lastly, if we do find an algorithm that can solve protein folding in polynomial time, wouldn't we destroy the field of cryptography? So maybe it's not such a good thing to develop fast protein folding algorithms? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but you may want to read [DNA Computing](https://irp.fas.org/agency/dod/jason/dna.pdf) (1995)

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/100734/35925)

Comment: [Complexity of protein folding](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02460704) (1993)

Comment: Protein folding calculates the end state - you didn't include how long it takes the protein to fold.

Comment: Also the lowest energy state could be arbitrarily close to other valid states and probably does get arbitrarily close as you try to make harder problems. Thermal motion will prevent the protein from settling in the exact lowest, in this case.